# Change value of input with jquery under this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:

```
$('.clickhere').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.row').children('.abc').hide(); // working
    $(this).closest('.row').children('.abc').children('input').value = ''; // not working
    $(this).closest('.bookingrow').children('.addressbox').children('input').value(''); // alternative - not working
});
```

html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='abc'>
     <input type='text' class='unknown' />
  </div>
  <div class="clickhere">hide</div>
</div>
```

my target is if i click the "clickhere" class, content under "abc" class will hide and whatever content added by customer on those input box, they will be clear.

same html used multiple time on the same form. that's why using "$(this)".
any solution? what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value, jQuery methods normally will return a jQuery object not a dom element reference so you would not have a properly called `.value`.

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.abc input').val('');
```

---

So

```
$('.clickhere').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //cache the value of .row since it is used multiple times
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
    $row.children('.abc').hide(); // working
    $row.find('.abc input').val('');
});
```